# Python: threading delay

Tags: python

Using the following to set a 30 second break every 60 seconds, however I do not want the break to start as soon as the script is first run. How can I add an initial delay to the first break?

```
def Breaktime():
  threading.Timer(60, Breaktime).start()
  print("Breaking for 30 seconds")
  time.sleep(30)

Breaktime()
```

Comment: Just add ‘time.sleep(30)’ before you call the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "30 second break"?  What you have there starts a new thread and puts that thread to sleep, uselessly.  It isn't going to affect the rest of your program.  Is that what you were after?  If you want the main code to pause, then you have to put the `sleep` in the main code.

Answer (score 1):

How about passing an argument?  Here is one way to do it.

```
def Breaktime(break_time=0):
  threading.Timer(60, Breaktime, kwargs={"break_time": 30}).start()
  print("Breaking for 30 seconds")
  time.sleep(break_time)

Breaktime()
```

Comment: The rest of the script continues to run when I do this, it prints that it's breaking but doesn't actually stop.